# Callable Statement

Tags: mysql, jdbc, callable-statement

I have created a stored procedure in MySQL and tried to call it by using the callable statement. I've got the following error:

```
[mysqld-5.1.53-community]PROCEDURE test.HI does not exist
```

Not sure how to continue further and don't know where to find the stored procedure in the database.

Comment: I suggest you post your code that would help others to suggest a solution. Regards

Comment: What stored procedure? How is it written? How did you call it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phpmyadmin, you can see stored procedures under `Routines` in your database page.